# Setting for keeping the states of Finder tabs in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, tabs

I upgraded to **macOS Catalina** recently. Before the update, I was able to **reinstate the last state of the Finder Tabs**.

[image: Tab State]

However, after the update, I am *unable to find any settings* which do this! Can anyone let me know how to deal with the situation, please?

Thanks in Advance for considering my request.

[image: Settings-> General]

Comment: Reinstate… after what action?

Comment: So here is the situation, I open the Finder and open many tabs(Lets say for explanation **Downloads**,  **Desktop** & **Applications** as shown in figure above). Now, I close it(the whole Finder window and not the individual tabs) using the x button on the top left. Then I click on the Finder again from the doc. Previously, when I do this, I used to get the Finder back with all tabs previously opened( **Downloads**,  **Desktop** & **Applications** from our example). However, after I upgraded to macOS Catalina, Finder just opens with the default(**Recents**) and all the previous tabs are lost.